# Protractor test : How click on button using text or class?(Best approach)

Tags: angularjs, protractor, gulp-protractor

I have code

```
<div class="button-wrapper">
    <button class="continue enabled">Continue</button>
</div>
```

I am using Angular JS e2e test.

I tried  `element(by.buttonText('Continue')).click();` to test.
Still getting error Failed:

```
 No element found using locator: by.buttonText("Continue")
```

Any help/suggestion?

Comment: The best thing here is to add `id`. Otherwise you have to find it by looking for `a` then `i` and if your hierarchy changes then you have to change the code.

Answer (score 0):

is the button clickable?
You can try:

```
    browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(element(by.buttonText('Continue')))
            .then(() => {
                element(by.buttonText('Continue')).click();
            });
```

or maybe:

```
element(by.partialButtonText(text));
```